# How can we put image as in the title bar of monodroid screen?

Tags: imageview, xamarin.android, titlebar

How can we put image as in the title bar of monodroid screen?

I tried using the following code, but it shows error as getwindow() is not a valid function here and I am not able to find a valid equivalent for this in monodroid.

```
        Boolean CustomTitleSupported = RequestWindowFeature (WindowFeatures.CustomTitle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Search);

         getwindow().setFeatureInt(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle, Resource.layout.titlebar);
```

Please help as the android method doesn't seem to work in mono.

Answer (score 2):

In Mono for Android, many cases where Java would have getXXXX/setXXXX methods get translated to properties named XXXX in order to align better with .NET's style. In this care, getWindow() becomes the [Window property](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=P%3aAndroid.App.Activity.Window) on Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me in Mono-droid.

Here getwindow() is just replaced by window as Greg pointed out.

```
 Boolean CustomTitleSupported = RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Search);

        if (CustomTitleSupported){

             Window.SetFeatureInt(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle, Resource.Layout.titlebar);
        };
```